# Toggle Inside Fragment

Tags: android

I have made one Activity with a NavigationView (opened with a toggle button):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer != null) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;

            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;

            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout, fragment).commit();
    item.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(item.getTitle());
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
}
```

When I select one item of NavigationView it starts a Fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    return view;
}
}
```

Problem: 
When I select the button ≡ to open the NavigationView inside Fragment and I select the items it doesn't open FirstFragment. 
If I swipe from the left to open NavigationView inside Fragment and I select the items it opens FirstFragment. 
How can I reuse onNavigationItemSelected from MyActivity on FirstFragment?

Edit:

This is the acitivity_layout.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ddffff"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    //FragmentLayout
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ddffff"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You're gonna have to better explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm still kinda confused. You mean the first `FragmentTransaction` doesn't work? Or the drawer doesn't open? You don't want another `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in your `Fragment`. There should just be one in the `Activity`.

Comment: When I select ≡, inside FirstFragment, it opens the NavigationView but when I select one item of NavigationView the FragmentTransaction does not work. If I swipe to the right instead of selecting ≡ it works fine.

Comment: That sounds like a layout problem. Please post your `Activity`'s layout XML.

Comment: I paste it on question.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I'm following the described behavior correctly, but when you transact a `Fragment` into `layout`, it's loading on top of your `Toolbar`. You want the `<include>` for the `Toolbar` to be in the `LinearLayout`, above the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: You are right it works. But now I have two actionbars (one above another). You know how can I solve that? Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You're using the same layout for your `Fragment` as for the `Activity` - `activity_layout`. The `Fragment` should have it's own different layout; one without a `Toolbar`, apparently.

Comment: Btw, I should point out that that was why the `NavigationView` wasn't working when you used the toggle in the `Fragment`. You were creating a duplicate of the `Activity`'s layout, and that toggle was opening a duplicate `NavigationView`, but that one wasn't setup, so clicking on it didn't do anything. When you dragged the drawer open, it was opening the main `NavigationView`, and that one would work as you were expecting. I'll stick all this in a proper answer later, when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this is that you're using the same layout in your `Fragment` as you are in the `Activity`, and the `Toolbar` is inside the container `ViewGroup` you transact the `Fragment` into. Once a `Fragment` has been loaded with its own `DrawerLayout` and `Toolbar`, it covers the `Activity`'s `Toolbar`, so nothing looks out of the ordinary. However, the toggle in the `Fragment` is operating the drawer in the `Fragment`, and that drawer is a second `NavigationView` that hasn't been setup like the one in the `Activity`, so nothing happens when you click on the drawer opened with the toggle. But, if you drag the drawer open, the one that's opening is actually the `Activity`'s drawer, and *that* `NavigationView` was setup correctly, so clicking on that one works as expected.

The first correction is to move the `Toolbar` - its `<include>` element, that is - to outside of the `RelativeLayout` you're using as the `Fragment` container. This will prevent the `Activity`'s `Toolbar` from being obscured when `Fragment`s are loaded.

The second step is to define separate, different layout XML files for the `Fragment`s. You don't want to use the same layout in the `Fragment`s as you are in the `Activity`, mostly because that's probably not really what you intend, and also because you really don't want to have multiple, redundant `DrawerLayout`s, `Toolbar`s, and `NavigationView`s, which can cause problems, as you've seen.